# Express $\operatorname{trace}(B'XB)$ in terms of $A$ and $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory

Given $A\in\Bbb R^{n\times n}$, $B\in\Bbb R^{n\times m}$, and $X>0$, s. t. [$X=A'XA-A'XB(I+B'XB)^{-1}B'XA,$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_Riccati_equation) where $A'$ is $A$ transpose.

Is it possible to express $\operatorname{trace}(B'XB)$ in terms of $A$ and $B$ only (without $X$)?

If it helps, $(A,B)$ is [stabilizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controllability#Stabilizability). Even for diagonal $A$, the answer is not obvious.

---

My attempt:

I only have few equalities that I managed to deduce:

1. $\operatorname{trace}(B'XB)=\operatorname{trace}(AX^{-1}A'X)-\operatorname{trace}(I)=\operatorname{trace}(AX^{-1}A'X)-n.$
2. $\operatorname{trace}(B'XB)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^m(B_i'XB_i)$, where $B_i$ is the $i$'th column of $B$.
3. Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}a_1&&\\&a_2&\\
   &&a_2\end{bmatrix}$, then [$\operatorname{trace}(B'XB)=a_1^2a_2^2 + a_2^2 -2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3705484/find-mathrmtrax-1ax). (i.e. independent of $B$)
4. $\det(A_1)^2+\cdots+\det(A_m)^2\geqslant \operatorname{trace}(AX^{-1}A'X)\geqslant m\sqrt[m]{\det(A)^2}$. To prove this part, we can do Wonham decomposition on $(A,B)$ then use 1 and 2 together with geometric mean.

Is there any tighter bound than 4?

Comment: Use `\operatorname{trace}` and `\det`.

Comment: Any information about $A$?

Comment: @RiverLi We assume that $(A,B)$ is stabilizable. Also we can assume that $(A,B)$ is in wonham or cyclic decomposition form, i.e. $A$ is upper block triangular or block diagonal and $B$ is upper block triangular with size of blocks are according to size of blocks in $A$. If it also doesn't help we can work on the case when $A$ is diagonal, but some diagonal elements must repeat, if diagonal elements don't repeat I have the answer.

Comment: @RiverLi also eigenvalues of $A$ are larger than $1$

Comment: @Lee  I wrote something.

Comment: @RiverLi thank you, I want to check it tomorrow via simulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $X = A^\mathsf{T}XA - A^\mathsf{T}XB(I + B^\mathsf{T}XB)^{-1}B^\mathsf{T}X A$, we have
$X = A^\mathsf{T}(I + XBB^\mathsf{T})^{-1}XA$, and $I + XBB^\mathsf{T} = XAX^{-1}A^\mathsf{T}$,
and $X^{-1} + BB^\mathsf{T} = AX^{-1}A^\mathsf{T}$.
Let $Y = X^{-1}$. We have
$$BB^\mathsf{T} = AYA^\mathsf{T} - Y \tag{1}$$
which is written as
$\mathrm{vec}(BB^\mathsf{T}) = (A \otimes A - I)\mathrm{vec}(Y)$ where $\otimes$ denote the Kronecker product.
See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product

Since the eigenvalues of $A$ are larger than $1$, we know that zero is not an eigenvalues of $(A \otimes A - I)$
and thus $(A \otimes A - I)$ is non-singular. Thus, we have $\mathrm{vec}(Y) = (A \otimes A - I)^{-1}\mathrm{vec}(BB^\mathsf{T})$, from which,
we get $Y$. We have $\mathrm{Tr}(B^\mathsf{T}XB) = \mathrm{Tr}(B^\mathsf{T}Y^{-1}B)$.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to continue this problem for specific case when A is diagonal. And simulation shows that in that case, $\mathrm{Tr}(B'XB)$ is always independent of $B$. I tried to prove it, and can see since we take inverse of $Y$, all $B$ somehow cancel each other, but I could prove it. Can you please help me?

Comment: @Lee It is interesting if $\mathrm{Tr}(B^\mathsf{T}XB)$ is independent of $B$. You may post a new question to focus on diagonal $A$.

Comment: ok, here is it https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4115464/287178