# Minimize $\mathrm{tr}(AX^{-1}A'X)$ such that $X\succ0$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, trace

Given $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$
\begin{array}{ll} \underset{X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}}{\text{min}} & \mathrm{tr}(AX^{-1}A'X).\\ \text{s.t.} & X\succ0\end{array}

("$X\succ0$" means that $X$ is symmetric positive definite matrix)

---

Special case when $A=\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 &  & \\
 & a_2 & \\
&&a_2
\end{bmatrix}$ was discussed here: [Find $\mathrm{tr}(AX^{-1}A'X).$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3705484/find-mathrmtrax-1ax)

Is it possible to linearize/convexify such problem? Or is there any good approximation methods?

Comment: What is $A'$ ? $A^T$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie yes, $A'$ means transpose of $A$